# I cannot adjust the brightness on Lubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, lubuntu, laptop, brightness

I am using a Samsung NP-X420 with Lubuntu 14.04. The screen is so bright that it irritates my eyes. When I press the brightness adjustment keys on the keyboard (Fn+down arrow), I can see the window that appears on the top right corner, which is showing that it is changing the brightness, but nothing happens. The bar is moving left and right but the brightness remains harsh.

Is there another way to adjust the brightness? Do I need to install drivers? If yes, then please tell me which ones. I am not so familiar with computer stuff.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i use `xbacklight` to control my laptop brightness, `sudo apt-get install xbacklight` and for operation just type on terminal `xbacklight -set 50`

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. This is what I get when I type

"xbacklight -set 50":
"No outputs have backlight property"

Comment: Do you perhaps have another suggestion @yusufhari? Thanks in advance.